# How to filter this efficiently as activity_logs has millions of rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a master table containing activities of a customer along with the time of that activity. For eg. when a user clicks on the app there is a log, when he adds something in the cart there is a log. All the customers activities are tracked on a DB along with the time of that activity. I have another table that contains data of the offers running on the app along with the time of the offer running. How to select all the users who ordered during the offer timing in SQL? There are different offers running at different times. I need to separate all the customers who did an activity during offer hours.
My idea for doing this is by somehow filtering table of customer logs via offer logs using time. Can anyone help?

Table A - activity_logs

| id | time | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:00 | log_in |
| 1 | 10:01 | item_add |
| 1 | 10:02 | check_out |
| 1 | 10:03 | payment |
| 2 | 10:05 | log_in |
| 2 | 10:10 | item_add |
| 2 | 10:11 | check_out |
| 2 | 10:12 | payment |
| 3 | 11:05 | log_in |
| 3 | 11:10 | item_add |
| 3 | 11:11 | check_out |
| 3 | 11:12 | payment |

Table B - offer_logs

| offer | time_on | time_off |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1g1 | 10:04 | 10:15 |

Expected Result -

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If one of user activites is within a range of an offer, it's **max** should be greater or equal than **time_on** of the offer and **min** should be less or equal than **time_off** of the offer.

But, the problem is **user5** who's activities happen only before **on_time** and after **off_time**. It requires to write additional query to validate each candidate user using **JOIN**.

```sql
WITH aggregates AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(time) min, MAX(time) max
    FROM activity_logs GROUP BY id
),
candidates AS (
  SELECT id, offer, time_on, time_off
    FROM aggregates a, offer_logs o
   WHERE min <= o.time_off AND max >= o.time_on
)
SELECT DISTINCT id 
  FROM activity_logs a 
  JOIN candidates c USING(id)
 WHERE a.time BETWEEN c.time_on AND c.time_off;
```

[image]